# Meteor/Cordova: is there a way to activate a atmosphere js package only on android?

Tags: android, iphone, cordova, meteor, meteor-packages

The amazing 255kb:cordova-keyboard package works perfectly, but because of some bug that I could not figure out it prevents me from building for iphone. How can I add a package only for android? Is this possible? I only need this package to handle some situations where users close the keyboard with the Android hardware back button.

Comment: I don't think that's possible, but perhaps you could show us the issue that prevents you from building for iOS?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Meteor's dynamic imports together with platform detection.

```
function isAndroid() {
  return navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("android") > -1;
}

async function getAndroidLib() {
  if(isAndroid) {
    return await import('path/to/lib');
  }
  else {
    return {};
  }
}
```

Comment: what is path/to/lib? what should I put in that file? the actual code of the package? or just the name of it?

Comment: a string which is the relative path to the library.

Comment: I m not sure the platform detection will work inside a cordova (mobile) app though... I have not done this myself before...